# What percentage of table A has data from table B?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
 +-----------+ 
 |  Students |
 +-----------+
 |  S_PK     | 
 |  Mike     |   
 |  Joe      |    
 |  Bob      |  
 |  Bill     |    
 +-----------+
```

Table 2:

```
 +--------+
 | Grades | 
 +--------+
 |  G_PK  |
 |   A    |      
 |   A    |       
 |   B    |       
 |   C    |    
 |  S_PK  |    
 +--------+
```

How do I put together a query that gives me the percentage of students that have As?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a table and a column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I do. Their TWO SEPARATE TABLES NOT COLUMNS. Maybe because I'm using the pipe symbol to seperate them and it's confusing everyone to see them as columns..ill fix that now

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little trick I learned from Gordon.

**Example**

```
Select Pct= avg(case when Grades='A' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
0.500000
```

**Edit Just for Fun**

```
Select [As] = avg(case when Grades='A' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
      ,[Bs] = avg(case when Grades='B' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
      ,[Cs] = avg(case when Grades='C' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
      ,[Ds] = avg(case when Grades='D' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
      ,[Fs] = avg(case when Grades='F' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
As          Bs          Cs          Ds          Fs
0.500000    0.250000    0.250000    0.000000    0.000000
```

> **EDIT - Updated Question**

```
Select (A.n*1.0) / B.Den
 From (Select Num=count(Distinct S_PK) from Grades where Grade='A') A
 Cross Join (Select Den=count(Distinct S_PK) from Students) B
```

Comment: Overachiever!!!! and complements to Gordon too... boy you're laying it on thick today. :P  as a note the reason why it's 1.0 and 0.0 is so SQL will force the system to avoid integer math giving you decimal results instead of just 0 or 1 depending on rounding.

Comment: @xQbert Does he know it's not a simple filter of a column? It's   totally two different tables.

Comment: @al56 I assumed the data presented was the result of a join between your two tables.  If not, how do you propose to join the two tables

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes it's through a join. My question was to get an example of that kind of query

Comment: @al56 Percentage of Students with A's or Percentage of A's ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Percentage of students with A's

Comment: @al56 See "EDIT - Updated Question"